# Перевести строку в число

Tags: php

Всем добрый день. Подскажите как перевести сроку в число. использую следующию махинацию

```
$today = date("d/m/Y");
 $fp = fopen('cb.xml', 'w');
 $ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,
      'http://www.cbr.ru/scripts/XML_daily.asp?date_req='.$today);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
curl_exec($ch);
fclose($fp);
curl_close ($ch);

$fp = fopen("cb.xml", "r");
if ($fp) 
{
while (!feof($fp))
{
$mytext[] = fgets($fp, 999);
}
}
else echo "Ошибка при открытии файла";

fclose($fp);

$str = $mytext['77'] = trim($mytext['77']);

$str = str_replace(',','.',$str);
//var_dump($str);
$cen = 100 * $str;
```

Пробовал разные варианты перевода строки в число но никак не выходит. Либо результат 0

Comment: intval(), settype() не пробовали?

Comment: (int)$str;

Comment: Пробовал выдает 0 никак не выходит

Comment: покажите, что выдает var_dump()

Comment: на данный момент без функций перевода в число string(22) "43.9814" если перевести то int(0)

Comment: согласитесь, что что-то тут не клеится: когда var_dump() выдает что строка имеет 22 знака, а мы видим 7, то ожидать что intval будет работать с этой строкой корректно - не стоит. Где еще 15 знаков? Что они из себя представляют? Имеет смысл распечатывать var_dump'ом все значения на всем протяжении их преобразования чтобы понять где проблема. Если есть debug - то еще лучше.

Comment: Где еще 15 знаков вопрос конечно очень интересный самому бы очень хотелось узнать...

Comment: Ну, Вы блин даете. У Вас чему $mytext['77'] равен? "<Value>43,8919</Value>"? И Вы это значение пытаетесь перевести в число?!!! Понятное дело, что 0 будет.

Comment: Точно походу в этом вся проблема ... Подскажи пожалуйста как выдернуть только число из $mytext['77']

Comment: preg_match - если грамотно, str_replace - если тупо напролом, но очень просто.

Comment: @alexsis20102, $result = (int)(strip_tags($mytext['77']));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если нужна целая часть - [`intval()`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.intval.php) вам в помощь, а если дробное - [`floatval()`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.floatval.php)

Попробуйте

```
var_dump(floatval($str));
```

**UPDATE:**

Будьте плз внимательнее! У вас в $str содержится не "`43.8919`", а "`<Value>43.8919</Value>`"

Понятное дело, что оно преобразует такую строку в 0, потому что первый символ - не цифра.

Используйте [`preg_match()`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.preg-match.php). Например, так

```
preg_match('#([\d\.,]+)#', $str, $result);
$str = floatval($result[1]);
```

Или как вариант, можно попробовать заменить `fgets()`, на `fgetss()`

Comment: Тот же результат 0